# How can I check a pdb for a particular dll exists in a directory using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, dll, directory, match, pdb-files

I have a parent Directory inside which there are multiple project folders.
How can I check in powershell whether a pdb exists for all the respective dlls inside all the project folders?

I tried the below but dont know how to match a pdb with the particular dll.

```
$source = "C:\ParentDir\*"
$Dir = get-childitem $source -recurse
$List = $Dir | where-object {$_.Name -like "*.dll"}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$source = ".\Projects\"
$dlls = Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Filter *.dll -Recurse | where {!$_.PSIsContainer}
foreach ($dll in $dlls)
{ 
    $pdb = $dll.FullName.Replace(".dll",".pdb") 
    if (!(Test-Path $pdb)) { Write-Output $dll }
}
```

It returns the fileinfo(dir) objects for every every dll that doesn't have a pdb. use `fullname` property to get filepath. I provided the long answer above so to easily show how it works. To shorten it, use:

```
$source = ".\Projects\"
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Filter *.dll -Recurse | where {!$_.PSIsContainer} | % { $pdb = $_.FullName.Replace(".dll",".pdb"); if (!(Test-Path $pdb)) { $_ } }
```

Comment: thanks for the response Graimer.. I tried your method and it works partially for me.. for pdb it shows the full file path.. Like: .\Projects\data\test1.pdb. whereas I need only that pdb name without the path.. and the path as a separate field.. can I do that?

Comment: ? It  returns PDB files? It worked fine for me. It should only return dll files that doesn't have a psb file. What ps version are you using? Are u getting different results using long or short method?

Comment: ya this works fine.. but instead I am getting all the dlls that have pdbs.. and the pdb shows up with full file path.. whereas i need pdb and file path separately:)

Comment: it should work on ps2.0 tested just now. if it returns dlls with pdb, then you might have missed the ! before (test-path ....). If it still don't work, try Shay's method. :-)  EDIT: if your foldernames end with ".dll" too, it would have included one entry per folder I guess, fixed it now.

Comment: input stringarray. You do this by seperating paths With comma(remember quotes around each path) `$Source = "c:\path1", "c:\path2"`

Answer (score 4):

Try this, it should output two columns, FullName, the dll path, and PDB which contains a boolean value indicating if there's a corresponding PDB file.

```
Get-ChildItem $source -Filter *.dll -Recurse | 
Select-Object FullName,@{n='PDB';e={ Test-Path ($_.FullName -replace 'dll$','pdb') -PathType Leaf }}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Shay! By using your script I get the dll which doesn't have the associated pdb with the directory path.. I actually want both the DLLs with and without the PDBs.. And How do I show this up in a report with different columns? Suppose in an xls file - DLL, PDB, Path.. Thanks Again!

Comment: The result include dll which have or don't have corresponding pdb file (true or false respectively is reported in the pdb property. To add extensions, add another the calculated property (like the one I used for PDB) and change it to match new extension.